# How to render a list retrieved from firebase

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase

I want to render a list in angular project with data retrieved from firebase, but I cannot render it to my list.

I tried on Angular 7

```
//this is my ts code
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { PassThrough } from 'stream';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  courses: any[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges().subscribe(courses =>{
        this.courses = courses;
        console.log(this.courses);
      });
    }
  }



//this is the html 
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
    {{course.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want it to show like this

- course1
- course2

but the list are rendered with only a dot like this

-

Comment: what is the `console.log(this.courses);` displaying

Comment: Do you see any JavaScript errors in your Browser?

Answer (score 0):

inside subscribe() `this` does not reference to `courses`  you need to assign `this` to another variable like `let self=this;`

**Try the following code i hope this will work for you**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { PassThrough } from 'stream';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  courses: any[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  let self=this;
  db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges().subscribe(courses =>{
        self.courses = courses;
        console.log(courses);
     });
  }
}
```

Comment: @Boris Ningthoujam try this

Answer (score 0):

Small issue, you cannot assign the node to this.courses

```
export class AppComponent {
  courses: any[];
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {

   db.list('/courses').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => 
        changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }))
      )
    ).subscribe(courses =>{
        this.courses = courses;
        console.log(this.courses);
      });

    }
  }
```

ref: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md

Also, make sure that course.value, "value" property exists in course object.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses">
    {{course.value}} <-- here ?? 
  </li>
</ul>
```